# Running large numbers of sites on IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, application-pools

On Windows 2003 (32 bit Standard Edition with 4GB of RAM) we would host around 1200 sites on a single server split across say 4 application pools. This has worked well for us for a number of years.

IIS7 seems to favour creating a separate application pool for each site and I am lead to believe that IIS application pools are somehow tuned better for this purpose.

Has anyone in the community had experience of this approach with large numbers of sites on a single server?

Answer (score 2):

If you managed to run it on Windows 2003 it should run on 2008

This case study claims that they can have 3000 application pools per server:

http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Detail.aspx?CaseStudyID=4000001285

Comment: In the question it says we run with ~1200 sites spread across a small number of app pools. I'm wondering about how well this would scale where each site has it's own app pool. But thanks for the linky though.

Comment: They are running 3000 sites each with their own app pool, so it should work for you, with similar hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The most I've gotten up to is about 20 sites per server, so nothing near your numbers.  I've got one app pool per site, and haven't had any problems.

I'm running on Web Edition with 2 Gigs of RAM per server.